# MVVM Light pass ViewModel to ObjectDataProvider via ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an `ObjectDataProvider` that binds to the `GetProducts()` method of my viewmodel:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GetProducts"
                    ObjectType="vm:MainViewModel"
                    MethodName="GetProducts">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <m:Subcategory Id="-1"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

As far as I understand this creates an instance of `MainViewModel` to call the method. Recently I started using MVVM Light and its `ViewModelLocator` class registers its own instance of the same viewmodel, so now I have two viewmodels instead of one.

That didn't feel right so I was wondering: is it possible to pass the viewmodel created by `ViewModelLocator` to the `ObjectDataProvider`?

I tried using a binding but `ObjectInstance` property is apparently not a dependency property so it can't be used here. How else can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by getting rid of `ObjectDataProvider` entirely and adding some properties to my viewmodel instead, e.g.

```
    // This property took place of MethodParameter[0]
    public Subcategory SelectedSubcategory
    {
        get { return _selectedSubcategory; }
        set
        {
            Set(() => SelectedSubcategory, ref _selectedSubcategory, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedSubcategory != null)
                return SelectedSubcategory.Products;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also needed to change respective bindings in XAML, e.g. this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetProducts},
                       Path=MethodParameters[0],
                       BindsDirectlyToSource=True,
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

turned into:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubcategory, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

Now I have only one viewmodel instance! Yay!